# SpeakTextAsync throw the exception "A callback was made on a garbage collected delegate" when use AudioConfig and PushAudioOutputStreamCallback

Tags: c#, naudio, azure-cognitive-services, speech-synthesis

I'm making a tool it use the MS cognitive speech service and Naudio to synthesize the text speech and play it on the specified audio device. I use the PushAudioOutputStreamCallback to write the audio data which from the azure to the wave provider of Naudio. But an exception *"A callback was made on a garbage collected delegate"* is thrown when SpeakTextAsync invoked. How to fix it?

This code will throw an exception at ***await speecher.SpeakTextAsync(txtSpeech.Text)***

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        WaveOut device;
        BufferedWaveProvider playback;
        SpeechSynthesizer speecher;
        PushNAudio push;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var fmt = new WaveFormat();
            fmt = fmt.AsStandardWaveFormat();
            playback = new BufferedWaveProvider(fmt);

            var cfg = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("xxxxx", "xxxxx");
            var asfmt = AudioStreamFormat.GetWaveFormatPCM((uint)fmt.SampleRate, (byte)fmt.BitsPerSample, (byte)fmt.Channels);
            push = new PushNAudio(playback);
            AudioConfig acfg = AudioConfig.FromStreamOutput(push, asfmt);
            speecher = new SpeechSynthesizer (cfg, acfg);

            device = new WaveOut();
            device.DeviceNumber = 1;
            device.Init(playback);
            device.Play();
        }

        public class PushNAudio : PushAudioOutputStreamCallback
        {
            private BufferedWaveProvider _provider;
            public PushNAudio(BufferedWaveProvider provider)
            {
                _provider = provider;
            }
            public override uint Write(byte[] dataBuffer)
            {
                _provider.AddSamples(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
                return (uint)dataBuffer.Length;
            }
        }

        private async void DoSpeech()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtSpeech.Text))
                return;

            /*Exception*/
            var result = await speecher.SpeakTextAsync(txtSpeech.Text);
            if (result.Reason == ResultReason.Canceled)
            {
                var details = SpeechSynthesisCancellationDetails.FromResult(result);
            }

        }

        private void TxtSpeech_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                DoSpeech();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

This Exception:

A callback was made on a garbage collected delegate of type 'Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.csharp!Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Internal.PushAudioStreamWriteDelegate::Invoke'. This may cause application crashes, corruption and data loss. When passing delegates to unmanaged code, they must be kept alive by the managed application until it is guaranteed that they will never be called.

The Stack:

Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.csharp.dll!Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.SpeechSynthesizer.SpeakTextAsync.AnonymousMethod__1()
Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.csharp.dll!Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.SpeechSynthesizer.DoAsyncSynthesisAction(System.Action synthImplAction)
Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.csharp.dll!Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.SpeechSynthesizer.SpeakTextAsync.AnonymousMethod__0()
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTaskSlot)
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(bool bPreventDoubleExecution)
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()

Comment: A wild guess, but have you tried assigning `txtSpeech.Text` to a variable before using it in the if statement and passing that variable to the if test and the async call?

Comment: Tried,same exception

Answer (score 0):

After multiple attempts, I found these codes can work well when target .net core. I think maybe the Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech have not been tested fully under the .net framework.